# Regex matching specific pattern with numbers. Allowed number 0 and greator than 5

Tags: javascript, regex

i want to allow 0 and greator than 5 numbers in an input field.

**Allowed Numbers:** 
0, 5, 10, 11, 12 ...

**Not Allowed Numbers**
negative number, 1,2 3, 4

```html
 <span matPrefix>$ </span>
 <input id="hourlyrate" type="number" pattern="^[+]?([0-9]+(?:[\.][0-9]*)?|\.[0-9]+)$"min="5"name="hourlyrate"#hourlyrate="ngModel"matInput[disabled]="!editRate"[(ngModel)]="skill.price"required>
 <span matSuffix>per 15 minutes</span>
 <mat-error *ngIf="hourlyrate.invalid">
   <span *ngIf="hourlyrate.errors?.required">This field is required.</span>
   <span *ngIf="hourlyrate.errors?.pattern">Minimum price should be $5.</span>
   <span *ngIf="hourlyrate.errors?.min">Minimum price should be $5.</span>
 </mat-error>
```

Comment: ...and what exactly have you tried so far? We can help you, but not write everything for you.

Comment: What about `6, 7, 8, 9`?

Comment: 6,7,8,9 are also allowed

Comment: Why it has to be regex?

Comment: Try detecting the `-` sign and 1, 2, 3, 4 and reverse the result.

Comment: I assume this is to use with the `pattern` attribute of a `<input pattern="" type="text">`, hence the regexp requirement.

Comment: `^(?![1234]$)\d+$`

Comment: @Toto ^(?![1234]$)\d+$ this worked.. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use:

```
^(?![1234]$)\d+$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^               # beginning of string
    (?!         # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't after:
        [1234]  # one of the digit 1 or 2 or 3 or 4
        $       # end of string
    )           # end lookahead
    \d+         # 1 or more digits
$               # end of string
```